# Postfix fails to send requeued (back to the active queue) deferred emails

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-bounces, queue

So, I've been digging into the pits of **Postfix** lately in order to administrate my mail server.
For various reasons, some of which I haven't yet explained, I ended up with lots of **deferred** emails, and here comes the question..

When the *queue manager* (`qmgr`) delivers the deferred emails to the *active active queue* all of the emails **fail to send with 0 smpt delay**, meaning they fail during negotiation.
**However**, when I explicitely send the corresponding queue IDs of those emails with `postqueue -i` all of them delivery successfully!

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
No matter how many times the *qmgr* delivers the mail to the *active queue* for the *smtp deamon* to send them they fail.

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/mail.log` or `/var/log/maillog`?

Comment: @SYN ofc I did. As I said I have become quite accustomed with Postfix and its internals